# What are these characters that I get suggested “ℬ ℱ ℳ ℛ ℰ”?

Tags: iphone, ios, internationalization

When I type on my iPhone running iOS 11 I get these characters as suggestions:

> ℬ ℱ ℳ ℛ ℰ

[image]

They come only for the letters "*B F M R E*”. They only appear for single letters and disappear as soon as a second letter is typed.

I have two keyboards active: German and English. I don’t have the smiley keyboard activated.

What are these characters? Are these letters for mathematical equiations? Is this a special font? Are more characters available? Why are they suggested?

Comment: What do you type to get these as suggestions? Autocorrect learns over time to adapt to each user.

Comment: @Christian That's what I thought. I get these characters suggested, when I hit one of the letters *B, F, M, R* or *E*. In the beginning it happend only on "E", the other characters came after some time.

Comment: To reset your autocorrect dictionary you can go to Setting -> General -> Reset -> Reset Keyboard Dictionary. This should prevent them from occurring but unfortunately I don't know what characters they are or why they appeared in the first place.

Comment: You could try going to http://asciivalue.com/ and typing the letters to find out what ASCII characters they are. They may help find out their origin.